# can I make ubuntu's terminal program automatically copy to the clipboard selected text and paste on right click?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, putty, gnome-terminal

i'm used to using putty on a window's machine.  With putty whatever you select is automatically on the clipboard without having to right click and select copy.  And right click just pastes.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A little known feature of the X server in Linux and other UNIX-like operating systems gets you half of the way there.

*Anything* you highlight in Linux, regardless of the program, is put into a special clipboard buffer, which you can paste using your mouse's middle (wheel) button (which is emulated on many laptops by pushing both buttons at the same time).  [You can also use a keyboard shortcut, if you like.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11889/pasting-x-selection-not-clipboard-contents-with-keyboard)

Unfortunately, I don't think you can change `gnome-terminal`'s right-click behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The solution involves you to download source code of gnome terminal and apply the [patch](http://www.taika.org/~tomba/gnome-terminal/right-button-paste.patch) and then you will need to build a package which will build deb packages and then you can just install from those packages.

For more clear instructions you can view this [page](http://www.taika.org/~tomba/gnome-terminal/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Adding this to ~/.Xresources (create if it doesn't exist) worked for me:

```
xterm*selectToClipboard: true
```

Just log out and back in, or do a restart. Selected text will then be automatically copied and you can paste it with middle-click (when middle-click is enabled in Gnome-Tweaks)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using xfce with ubuntu. In that terminal you need to check the box:

Edit->Preferences->General->Automatically copy selection to clipboard

Paste is with middle click. I dunno about paste with right click.

This is the screen from xfce4-terminal 0.8.9.1:

[image]

Comment: "Automatically copy selection" is not an option

Comment: I just pasted a screen shot to prove I'm not making this up. :-) @PhilipRego maybe you are using a different version of xfce4-terminal?

Comment: You didn't say you were using that terminal. I'm using GNOME Terminal Version 3.46.8. The question is tagged gnome-terminal, so the correct answer is you cannot copy to the clipboard with gnome-terminal on highlight.

Comment: You're right, I said I was using xfce and referred to "that terminal" by which I meant xfce4-terminal. A bit unclear, I guess. The question didn't specify gnome or gnome-terminal, only Ubuntu, and it is tagged with 'putty' as well... I did not limit myself to those tags.  I saw no answer for myself, an Ubuntu xfce user, and the question applies to xfce as well. We could add the xfce tag too?

Answer (score -1):

"Terminator" emulator has this feature built-in.
Mark the text from the "Terminator" and it's going to your clipboard.